# Running linux with gpsd and ntpd and communication via shared memory

Tags: linux, usb, ntpd, gpsd

I have gpsd running because I want the time information supplied via the shared memory as a time source for ntpd. For strange reasons, which I do not understand, this information is only available if gpsd is started with the "-n" flag.

While both gpsd and ntpd are running, I plug another device on the USB interface, but it has the same CP2104 chip as the GPS mouse. This device is recognized but the device is immediately monopolized by the PPS routines of the kernel, with a message "new PPS source usbserial#" in the kernel log available via dmesg. But this device is not a GPS device and now the device is not more avaible for the software which needs it.

What can I do to avoid this harmful behaviour ?

Is it possible to disable the use of the PPS by the kernel or gpsd ?

Comment: I think you need to search the udev rules. I also think you should not use a usb gps puck to sync time to, it's only slightly better than useless.There is no PPS on it. Get a serial one and an sbc.

Comment: I'm aware about the limitations of the use of a GPS mouse without PPS. But in many circumstances, this precision is sufficient. Unfortunately, at my knowledge, the udev rules do not offer a way to avoid that the PPS software monopolize the newly connected serial interface. But I may be wrong.